# Unable to plot two functions with tkz-fct

Tags: plot, gnuplot, tkz-fct

I'm trying to use `tkz-fct` to plot some simple functions. One function is plotted right, but when I add another function in some other part of the document all the functions along the whole document become the same.

When I compile the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5]
\tkzGrid \tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[domain = 0:5]{1/x}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is correct:

[image]

But when I try to plot any other function, the two plots become the same. It doesn't matter if is in the same environment or anywhere else in the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5]
\tkzGrid \tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[domain = 0:5]{1/x}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=-1,xmax=5,ymax=3]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[domain = 1:5]{log(x)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it is useful I have an up to date TeXlive 2022 and Gnuplot Version 5.4 patchlevel 4. My compilation chain is

```
lualatex
gnuplot
lualatex
```

The same problem appears if the compilation method is `pdflatex`. I hope someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you try giving your functions IDs? Say `\tkzFct[domain=0:5, id=rec]{1/x}` and `\tkzFct[domain=1:5, id=log]{log(x)}`. It appears tkz gives both the same id which results in the second function to overwrite the gnuplot directive and more importantly gnuplot's result still having the same name so that the second TeX run uses the same result for both functions.

Comment: After giving IDs to functions, it only prints the axes and the grid, but no the plot of the function (even if it is only one)

Comment: When I'm compiling your second example – the one with the two functions – in Overleaf it appears t(i)kz calls gnuplot during the compilation of the document and then it is not a problem that both functions have the same id/name (only the last will survive and they need to be reevaluated every time). I don't think it is necessary to do tex → gnuplot → tex but if you do, you need different named plots? I think you will need to inspect the log file as well as the plot-files that get created to figure out where the process breaks down.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel is exactly as you said. In Overleaf the example works as expected. I am doing tex → gnuplot → tex because is what I understand from the pages 7 -- 9 of the manual. I suppose I will copy the latexmk from overleaf to make it work. But I will inspect the log and relevant files